# Scrolling two widgets using single scrollbar in TCL/TK.

Tags: user-interface, scrollbar, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have created two tree control widgets and a scrollbar widget. Now i am trying to create a functionality where the user would have choice of using scrollbar in the sense that there will be radiobutton options which would decide which widget gets scrolled with the scrollbar. I got some idea for how to scroll two widgets together from [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9254). But not sure how to create a switchable scrollbar. My code is below :

```
package require Tk
package require treectrl

namespace eval ::at::GUI {
  variable Priv;
  variable OptionsRB;

  set Priv(treePrimary) "";
  set Priv(treeSecondary) "";
  set Priv(treeScrollbar) "";

  if { ![info exists OptionsRB] } { 
    set OptionsRB(scrollTree) "LeftTree";
  }
}

proc ::at::GUI::DrawGUI {} {
  variable Priv;

  set frm_treeFrame [ttk::labelframe .treeFrame -text "Tree Area"];      
  set Priv(treePrimary) [treectrl $frm_treeFrame.treePrimary]
  set Priv(treeSecondary) [treectrl $frm_treeFrame.treeSecondary]    
  set Priv(treeScrollbar) [ttk::scrollbar $frm_treeFrame.sb_treeScroll -command "::at::GUI::yview"]

  grid $Priv(treePrimary) $Priv(treeSecondary) $Priv(treeScrollbar) -sticky news;
  grid columnconfigure $frm_treeFrame 0 -weight 1;
  grid columnconfigure $frm_treeFrame 1 -weight 1;
  grid rowconfigure $frm_treeFrame 0 -weight 1;

  set frm_ST [ttk::labelframe .scrollTreeOptions -text "Scroll Option"];  
  set rb_leftTree [ttk::radiobutton $frm_ST.rb1 -text "Left Tree" -variable [namespace current]::OptionsRB(scrollTree) -value LeftTree -command [namespace current]::configScroll ]
  set rb_rightTree [ttk::radiobutton $frm_ST.rb2 -text "Right Tree" -variable [namespace current]::OptionsRB(scrollTree) -value RightTree -command [namespace current]::configScroll ] 
  set rb_bothTree [ttk::radiobutton $frm_ST.rb3 -text "Both Tree" -variable [namespace current]::OptionsRB(scrollTree) -value BothTree -command [namespace current]::configScroll ] 

  grid $rb_leftTree -row 1 -padx {30 5} -pady 5 -sticky w
  grid $rb_rightTree -row 2 -padx {30 5} -pady 5 -sticky w
  grid $rb_bothTree -row 3 -padx {30 5} -pady 5 -sticky w

  # Grid all the frames in main window. 
  grid $frm_treeFrame -sticky news;
  grid $frm_ST -sticky news;

  ##############################
  ::at::GUI::CreateLemes $Priv(treePrimary)
  ::at::GUI::CreateLemes $Priv(treeSecondary)

  foreach tree [list $Priv(treePrimary) $Priv(treeSecondary)] {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 20} {incr i} {
      set parent [expr {int(rand()*$i)}]
      $tree item create -tag item$i -button auto
      $tree item lastchild $parent item$i
      $tree item text item$i name item$i
    }
  }
  return;  
}

proc ::at::GUI::CreateLemes {T} {
  $T element create rect rect -fill [list blue selected]
  $T element create name text

  set S [$T style create nameStyle]
  $T style elements $S {rect name};
  $T style layout $S rect -detach yes -iexpand xy;
  $T style layout $S name -detach no -iexpand xy -expand e;

  $T column create -tag name -itemstyle $S -text Items
  $T configure -treecolumn first;
}

proc ::at::GUI::configScroll {args}  {
  variable Priv;
  variable OptionsRB;

  if {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "LeftTree"} {
    #$Priv(treeSecondary) -yscrollcommand "";
    $Priv(treePrimary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "RightTree"} {
    #$Priv(treePrimary) -yscrollcommand "";
    $Priv(treeSecondary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "BothTree"} {
    $Priv(treePrimary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
    $Priv(treeSecondary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
  }
}

proc ::at::GUI::yset {sb args}  {
  uplevel [linsert $args 0 $sb set]
  ::at::GUI::yview moveto [lindex [$sb get] 0]
}

proc ::at::GUI::yview {args}  {
  variable Priv;
  variable OptionsRB;
  if {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "LeftTree"} {
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treePrimary) yview];
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "RightTree"} {
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treeSecondary) yview];
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "BothTree"} {
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treePrimary) yview];
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treeSecondary) yview];
  }
}
```

The thing is that whenever i try to click on the radiobuttion, i get an error saying :

> bad command "-yscrollcommand": must be activate, bbox, canvasx,
>   canvasy, cget, collapse, column, compare, configure, contentbox,
>   debug, depth, dragimage, element, expand, gradient, header, identify,
>   index, item, marquee, notify, numcolumns, numitems, orphans, range,
>   scan, see, selection, state, style, theme, toggle, xview, or yview bad
>   command "-yscrollcommand": must be activate, bbox, canvasx, canvasy,
>   cget, collapse, column, compare, configure, contentbox, debug, depth,
>   dragimage, element, expand, gradient, header, identify, index, item,
>   marquee, notify, numcolumns, numitems, orphans, range, scan, see,
>   selection, state, style, theme, toggle, xview, or yview
>       while executing "$Priv(treeSecondary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)""
>       (procedure "::at::GUI::configScroll" line 10)
>       invoked from within "::at::GUI::configScroll"
>       invoked from within ".scrollTreeOptions.rb2 invoke "
>       invoked from within ".scrollTreeOptions.rb2 instate {pressed !disabled} { .scrollTreeOptions.rb2 state !pressed;
>   .scrollTreeOptions.rb2 invoke } "
>       (command bound to event)

But the funny part is, even though i get the error, if i move the scrollbar, it does switch between the widget and works as desired. But the error is something i am not able to understand.

This is my very first TK project so I am not sure if I am missing some crucial information. Any comments??

Comment: It is a good idea to use `list` or a proc to build your callbacks, can make them faster e.g. `-yscrollcommand [list ::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is the key. Indeed the command contained in the `Priv(treeSecondary)` variable does not have a subcommand named `-yscrollcommand`. I think you want to use the `configure` subcommand to change the value of the `-yscrollcommand` option. Try something like:

```
$Priv(treeSecondary) configure -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)"
```